# glDrawElements throws an exception without error code

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw a simple triangle and set the buffers as follows;

```
triangle t;
point3f vertices[] = { t.p1(), t.p2(), t.p3() };
GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };

gl_vertex_array vao{ 3 };
vao.bind_vertex_array();

gl_vertex_buffer position_vbo{ buffer_type::array_buf };
position_vbo.bind_vertex_buffer();
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], 
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
position_vbo.unbind_vertex_buffer();

gl_vertex_buffer index_vbo{ buffer_type::element_array_buf };
index_vbo.bind_vertex_buffer();
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices[0], 
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
index_vbo.unbind_vertex_buffer();

vao.unbind_vertex_array();
```

Setting up of buffers and VAOs are fine I think, I checked with `glGetError` at each stage and everything seems to be working. On my render function, I do the following:

```
glClearColor(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.6f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

o.vao.bind_vertex_array();
o.sp.use_program();

GLenum error = glGetError();
assert(error == GL_NO_ERROR);
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
error = glGetError();
assert(error == GL_NO_ERROR);

o.sp.unuse_program();
o.vao.unbind_vertex_array();
```

This rendering call with `glDrawArrays` works just fine but when I try to render with `glDrawElements`, I get an exception thrown. Moreover, this is hard exception. I can't go to the next line to see the error code. I didn't know that OpenGl calls could throw. I am stuck here. What might be the problem?

Here is a similar discussion

[nvoglv32.dll throws the exception](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/720651/access-violation-in-nvoglv32-dll-how-do-i-track-down-the-problem-/)

Comment: probably access violation.

Comment: Sounds like you might be setting up the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` incorrectly.

Comment: I previously surrounded buffer creation sites with `glGetError` calls and those were working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the VAO setup code. The index buffer gets unbound before the VAO is unbound:

```
index_vbo.unbind_vertex_buffer();
vao.unbind_vertex_array();
```

Since the VAO always stores the last state of the bound `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, this is effectively unbinding the index buffer. The exception happens then because you try to read from a not bound index buffer. The solution should be to exchange these two lines and unbind the VAO first:

```
vao.unbind_vertex_array();
index_vbo.unbind_vertex_buffer();
```

As Nicol Bolas mentioned in the comments: You can actually leave away the unbinding of the element buffer completely. When the VAO gets unbound, there is no element buffer bound anymore.

Comment: Does similar thing happen with `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`s? Or do they notified to `VAO` at the site of calling `glVertexAttribPointer`?

Comment: `GL_ARRAY_BUFFERS` are saved when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called. I guess this is because there can be more than one `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` in a VAO but only one `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: @BDL: The solution should be to not unbind the index buffer at all. Once you unbind the VAO, there *is no* index buffer. So unbinding it serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks, I will add that to the answer.